# why virual host when i enter redirect http to https?

Tags: apache, http, browser, https

I notice when I made any virtual host anything.app or anything.dev
browser redirects from http to https 
where i can not open the virual host 
I notice also when i make it like that : anything.locaL
It open http correctly 
so what is the reason for that?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https

Comment: https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-our-new-app-domain-is-first-to-bake-in-https-to-make-browsing-safer/